# MongoDB schema design for Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: mongodb, nosql, many-to-many, schema

I'm facing a problem to the Many-to-Many relationship in NoSQL schema. I found several guides and there are two ways to handle it -

1. store the relationship in both collections (http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/schemabasics/)

```
Student: [ 
 { _id: 1, name: Hei, courseId: [ 1001, 1002, ... ] }
 { _id: 2, name: Vivian, courseId: [ 1001, 1003, ... ] }, 
... ]

Course: [ 
 { _id: 1001, name: Database Design, studentId: [ 1, 2, ... ] }, 
 { _id: 1002, name: Big Data Analysis, studentId: [ 1, ... ] },
... ]
```

2. store the relationship in third table (https://www.techighness.com/post/nosql-many-to-many-bound-unbound-associative-examples/)

```
Student: [ 
 { _id: 1, name: Hei }, 
 { _id: 2, name: Vivian }, 
...]

Course: [
 { _id: 1001, name: Database Design }, 
 { _id: 1002, name: Big Data Analysis }, 
...]

Registration: [
 { studentId: 1, courseId: 1001 }, 
 { studentId: 1, courseId: 1002 }, 
 { studentId: 2, courseId: 1001 }, 
 { studentId: 2, courseId: 1003 }, 
...]
```

I think the second approach would be better because duplication data exists in first approach, but I find difficulty in second approach - if the query is complicated then it's difficult to extract what I need (e.g. to search the courses based on keyword and identify which courses are registered by the student). In this case I find the query is much easier in first approach.

Which way would be better one for handling Many-to-Many relationship in NoSQL structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion both the structures are OK and it is hard to say which is better.
There is a good article at: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3
See the 6th rule: "...As always with MongoDB, how you model your data depends – entirely – on your particular application’s data access patterns. You want to structure your data to match the ways that your application queries and updates it. ..."